# Measure-Command reports inaccurate time?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I was to measure the execution time for, however when I use Measure-Command I receive what appears to be inaccurate information. For example I have timed the script myself and its takes roughly about 15 seconds to complete. However here are the last two outputs. As you can see one is in negative numbers and the other is reporting only 1 second. Any clue as to what is going on?

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : -538
Ticks             : -5382963
TotalDays         : -6.23028125E-06
TotalHours        : -0.00014952675
TotalMinutes      : -0.008971605
TotalSeconds      : -0.5382963
TotalMilliseconds : -538.2963




Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 629
Ticks             : 16299566
TotalDays         : 1.88652384259259E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000452765722222222
TotalMinutes      : 0.0271659433333333
TotalSeconds      : 1.6299566
TotalMilliseconds : 1629.9566
```

Here is the command I am running Measure-Command {MoveVM-Folder.ps1}. Below are the contents of the MoveVM-Folder script.

```
$VMs = Get-VM -Location $Cluster 
$Imports = Import-Csv $ImportFile 
foreach ($Import in $Imports) 
{ $VMs | where {$_.Name -eq $Import.VMName} | Move-VM -Destination $Import.DestFolder }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You will have to provide some information on how you are using measure-command. What are you putting in the scriptblock?

Comment: Best would be if you could use START-TRANSCRIPT, run it again, use STOP-TRANSCRIPT and post the transcript.

Comment: I use Get-PerformanceHistory http://poshcode.org/683 so I can get this information after the fact... instead of having to change how I execute the command.

Comment: Added the exact script that I am running. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try: "Measure-Command {MoveVM-Folder.ps1 | Out-Default}"... I only state this because I was using a simple "gwmi -query "select * from win32_process"" and without the "| Out-Default", the time reported is 21 miliseconds, however with the Out-default, the time reported is 1 sec, 867 miliseconds.  This could be due to the printing of the text to the console window, but if your script has any error handling etc., then you should see it with the out-default pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens irregularly, then it could just be a simple explanation that your system clock is "wrong" and got updated during the run.